# express session disappears as soon a I reload front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am using express sessions and cookies to keep logged in a session, but it is not working, as soon as I reload the react app to check if the session works, all I get is the req.session.user was deleted (undefined), here's my express code below:

```
app.use(session({
  key: "userId",
  secret: "test",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
  }
}))

app.get("/login", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.user)
  if (req.session.user) {

    res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user })
  }
  else {
    res.send({ loggedIn: false });
  }
})
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body) {
      const { formData } = req.body;


      const sqlfetch = "Select * FROM users WHERE username=?"
      await db.query(sqlfetch, formData.username, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
        }

        else if (result.length > 0) {
          await bcrypt.compare(formData.pass, result[0].pass, (error, response) => {
            console.log(response)
            if (response) {
              req.session.user = result
              res.send({ loggedIn: true })
            }

            else {
              return res.send({ loggedIn: false }).status(401);

            }
          });
          
        }

      });

    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

})
```

but all I get is loggedIn:false
any help please??
Thank you

Comment: Is your frontend and backend is running on same origin ?

Comment: @AmeerHamza on localhost yes

Comment: @AmeerHamza  this is the cors code:  app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true, //allowing cookies to be true
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],

  })
);